# Wordpress settings API VS Table In Database?

Tags: settings-api

I have created an options page for my plugin using Settings API. Now I want to create another tab where user will create records. He will also like to delete/edit records. There will be 10-20 records only. I want to stick with settings API for these records (Single field in database) but I am at a lose to decide if it is possible with settings API. If yes, can you guide me how as user will like to edit/delete records as well. Or should i opt for a table in database?

Comment: You should use Custom Post Types. No extra table, no missuse of Settings API.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually its a custom slider where user will upload slides. So i think a custom table will be appropriate if Settings API is a misuse in this scenario.

Comment: No, just use CPTs with Title field, WYSIWYG or textarea for caption and featured image for the actual image. This way later themes can also make use of it. Just name the CPT "slider". [Here´s a read why sliders & carousels are not a good choice](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective).

Comment: @kaiser can you make your comment your answer so that i can accept it. thanks

Comment: N/p - just done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Custom Post Types. No extra table, no missuse of Settings API.

Use CPTs with Title field, WYSIWYG/textarea (for caption) & a featured image (for the actual slider image). This way later themes can also make use of it. Just name the CPT "slider".

[Here´s a read why sliders & carousels are not a good choice.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective)